# Snackbar and other animations stopped working on some Android devices

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have a very odd issue that I cannot figure out. I was not an issue until recently but I can't seem to revert back to prevent it. Also the other odd thing is it works on some devices and others it does not.

The issue is animations. One in particular is snack bar. The snackbar should animate up and down but it is not. it just shows then hides. check video below to see issue.

[Video of issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bm3gsya4ozo5q6v/2016_05_13_19_31_04.mp4?dl=0)

Here is the Android code to animate the snackbar in

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        ViewCompat.setTranslationY(mView, mView.getHeight());
        ViewCompat.animate(mView)
                .translationY(0f)
                .setInterpolator(FAST_OUT_SLOW_IN_INTERPOLATOR)
                .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION)
                .setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(View view) {
                        mView.animateChildrenIn(ANIMATION_DURATION - ANIMATION_FADE_DURATION,
                                ANIMATION_FADE_DURATION);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                        onViewShown();
                    }
                }).start();
    }
```

Its using ViewCompat for the v4 Library. I have other animations working in another activity working fine. Also the issue is not on just one activity its all of them. That makes me think its system wide somehow. But they all use different internal themes but all extend Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.

Here is my main layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:elevation="4dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabText"
        app:tabMinWidth="@dimen/tab_minwidth"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"/>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>

<fr.castorflex.android.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/base_progressSpinner"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:cpb_color="@color/spinner"
    app:cpb_rotation_speed="1.0"
    app:cpb_sweep_speed="1.0"
    app:cpb_stroke_width="4dp"
    app:cpb_min_sweep_angle="10"
    app:cpb_max_sweep_angle="300"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_upload"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/content_frame"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/app_fab_upload"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/big_padding"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_social"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_muzei"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/content_frame"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/app_fab_muzei"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/big_padding"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_social"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Devices it works on**

- Nexus 9 (Marshmallow)
- Nexus 4 (KitKat)
- Galaxy S7 (Marshmallow)

**Devices it does not work**

- Droid Turbo 2 (Marshmallow)
- Galaxy S7 (Marshmallow) *my device works, my testers does not
- Nexus 6p (Android N)

The other animation issues are with Switches. I have 2 in same layout and one stutters when switched and the other just switches with no animation.

I also have a LayoutTransition set to my AppBarLayout to animation the hiding/showing of my TabLayout and it works fine and all devices

Comment: the video link is broken

Comment: on Samsung J5 pro (Nougat) doesn't work either.

Comment: All the Moto lineup has the same problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found the reason why this is happening, but not how to fix yet.

```
/**
 * Returns true if we should animate the Snackbar view in/out.
 */
private boolean shouldAnimate() {
    return !mAccessibilityManager.isEnabled();
}
```

That is called by Snackbar class and is false on working devices, and true on devices not working. Does anyone know about this?

So after i disabled lastpass in my system settings, accessibility the snackbar now animates as it should. That is crazy how that works. Nova launcher has the same affect. I guess any service in accessibility that is enabled will cause the snackbar animation to not work.

Comment: I can confirm this happens to me too. Had Join by JoaoApps and Lastpass enabled for accessibility and disabling both allowed the snackbar to animate.

Comment: Turns out that apparently this is intended behavior, [see here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206416#c2). Frustrating to say the least, especially since that would mean Droid Turbo users would have to disable Moto Voice to see Snackbar animations. One thing I noticed, however, is that Snackbars in Google's Inbox app still animate - at least it's possible somehow, now just to figure it out...

Comment: Has anyone found a solution yet?

Answer (score 16):

As Bignadad mentioned, the problem is that any accessibility feature, including things like password managers, disables the snackbar animations. Google, as of this edit, [has fixed this for AndroidX but not the Design support library](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37092972)

Because Snackbar's base class, BaseTransientBottomBar, handles the animation, with package private, final methods, you have two choices if you want to fix it: roll your own snackbar from scratch, or use a more hacky solution with reflection:

Kotlin example:

```
// Only force when necessary, and don't animate when TalkBack or similar services are enabled
val shouldForceAnimate = !accessibilityManager.isEnabled && accessibilityManager.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN).isEmpty()

Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, text, duration).apply {
    if (shouldForceAnimate) {
        try {
            val accManagerField = BaseTransientBottomBar::class.java.getDeclaredField("mAccessibilityManager")
            accManagerField.isAccessible = true
            val accManager = accManagerField.get(this)
            AccessibilityManager::class.java.getDeclaredField("mIsEnabled").apply {
                isAccessible = true
                setBoolean(accManager, false)
            }
            accManagerField.set(this, accManager)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("Snackbar", "Reflection error: $e")
        }
    }
}.show()
```

Java example:

```
// Only force when necessary, and don't animate when TalkBack or similar services are enabled
boolean shouldForceAnimate = !accessibilityManager.isEnabled() && accessibilityManager.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN).size == 0;

Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, text, duration);
if(shouldForceAnimate){
    try {
        Field accManagerField = BaseTransientBottomBar.class.getDeclaredField("mAccessibilityManager");
        accManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        AccessibilityManager accManager = (AccessibilityManager) accManagerField.get(snackbar);
        Field isEnabledField = AccessibilityManager.class.getDeclaredField("mIsEnabled");
        isEnabledField.setAccessible(true);
        isEnabledField.setBoolean(accManager, false);
        accManagerField.set(snackbar, accManager);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Snackbar", "Reflection error: " + e.toString());
    }
}
snackbar.show();
```

I'd love a third option here, but I'm not aware of one, at least until AndroidX gets out of beta with the proper fix.

Comment: Once you run the code above you are able to call .show() directly in all other Snackbar instances without using this reflection. I'd like to recommend you to create a wrapper class to handle if you already run the reflection above and then just call .show()

Comment: My app is based on the accesibility service which analyzes text speech, so it's really frustrating that this animation would not work. This seems to be the only option, thank you.

Comment: "One step forward, two steps backwards" - Google

Comment: Don't do this unless you don't mind ruining the experience for the visually impaired: TalkBack will stop working once a snackbar is shown, rendering the app useless for them.

Comment: Ruining the app for the visually impaired can be averted with a simple fix: only run the code when `accessibilityManager.isTouchExplorationEnabled` is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed since Material Components for Android 1.0.0-alpha3 with [this commit](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/7aff9d2e8b5d62d3d7c554d3debfe9f1a11a7c77).

Use it instead of the Design Library (which is the way to go if you're using [AndroidX](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html)):

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_components_version"
```

Comment: This is only the case if the accessibility services in use do not use FEEDBACK_SPOKEN, but still better than nothing!