# SnackBar appear animation

Tags: java, android, snackbar

In my app I have a SnackBar that appears when a button is pressed.

```
Snackbar.make(v, "Enter valid data", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In the above code, v is the view obtained in the onClick event of a FloatingActionButton.

In the default SnackBar, it appears with a sliding up animation. In my app, the animation doesn't show. It just appears without any animation. Any way to force the animation to show?

Here's the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout               
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/loginRootView"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back_pattern">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/loginToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/loginCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/loginNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Mobile Number"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:textColor="#666666" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/loginNumber"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColor="#666666" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/loginForgotPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loginPassword"
                android:layout_below="@+id/loginPassword"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Forgot Password?" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginCard"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-43dp"
        android:background="#12af1c"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_36dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginSignUpLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginCard"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="New user? Register here."
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Snackbar and other animations stopped working on some Android devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221914/snackbar-and-other-animations-stopped-working-on-some-android-devices)

Comment: It looks like the fix is coming https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37092972#comment37

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ended up running into my Snackbar animations not working also. It turned out to be that I had another app which had accessibility options enabled which disables certain animations such as the Snackbar animation.

See post #5 by Chris: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206416

> The check is AccessibilityManager.isEnabled(), which returns true when
>   any accessibility service is enabled. I've just check on various API
>   levels Snackbar is working fine without an accessibility service
>   enabled.

In my case I had GIF Keyboard installed and enabled as an accessbility option. Going into Settings -> Accessibility and turning off GIF Keyboard made the animations start appearing in my app.

Comment: How am I supposed to force that in those cases? I've noticed that Inbox app's snackbar works with the right animation, even with Accessibility Settings enabled. While my app doesn't :|

Comment: @Cesarsk I can only guess they use a custom Snackbar.

Comment: FYI I just got the same problem, and it's not just the GIF keyboard. It was LastPass for me, so I guess if you have ANY "Services" turned on it will break -_-

Answer (score 0):

Up the version of your support design to 23.4.0

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```